# How to remove a white space in between url in android?

Tags: android

How do I remove the white space that are in front and back of &

http://chemist.com:8080/eShop/search_results.jsp?IDNUMBER=BB55-7344 & Source=BuildingBlocks

Comment: Where does the URL come from?  Is is a string object you have?

Comment: It comes from a server. i need to redirect this url to another page And it does go as there is white space. The original url has a and instead of & i have replace it thus i get the whitespace

Comment: Please show the code where you replace a with &

Comment: if(result.contains("and"){
   {
      resultnew=result.replace("and","&").toString();
      resultnew.replaceAll(" ","").trim();
      
   }
   Here is my code

Comment: Can you provide the original URL with the "and"?

Comment: http://chemistryon.com:8080/eShop/search_results.jsp?IDNUMBER=BB55-7344 and Source=BuildingBlocks

Answer (score 5):

Try :

```
urlString = urlString.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

This code replaces all the white space.

Comment: Or just `.replace(" ", "%20");`.

Answer (score 4):

```
String newUrl = oldUrl.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi i have tried this but does not work.

Comment: @user1310156, Please clarify what "does not work" means.

Comment: the repalceAll(" ",""); function odes not work for me over here

Comment: @user1310156, Why doesn't it work? What happens? I won't be able to help you if you won't describe your issue properly.

Comment: The problem is that this url is got from a server and this url it self contains and insted of & so i replaced and with & but the and in original url has white spaces so it does not remove it

Comment: @user1310156, You just need to use replaceAll on the final URL, it will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
String newURI = oldURI.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(result.contains(" and "){ 
      resultnew = result.replace(" and ","&amp").toString(); 
}
```

You don't really need the "if" check, although it is faster (unless result ***always*** contains " and ") as replace() will return the input string if " and " is not found.  You also don't need the toString() since replace() returns a String.

Comment: Thank you but there is no effect of this the white space does not go.

Comment: The white space does not go or the and is not replaced? (ie the if content is executed or not?)

Comment: Please show the value of resultNew